# Where can I find the table/data that tracks commits linked to work items in the TFS database?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, tfs

I'm trying to build a query that tracks completed work items without associated commits.  Thanks!

Comment: Writing queries directly against the TFS operational store is not support nor recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Just as Daniel mentioned writing queries directly against the TFS operational store is not support nor recommended.

However you can use the extension [WIQL Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor) to achieve it:

Install the Wiql Editor for your TFS Collection, then enter the completed below query to get the work items without associated commits. (Just change the state to the corresponding value based on your process settings, eg "**Closed**" or "**Done**")

```
SELECT
        [System.Id],
        [System.WorkItemType],
        [System.Title],
        [System.State],
        [System.AreaPath],
        [System.IterationPath]

FROM workitems
WHERE 
        [System.TeamProject] = @project  
AND     [System.State] = 'Closed'

AND [system.History] NOT CONTAINS 'Associated with commit'
ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
```

Reference below screenshot:
[image]

Comment: @nhardy Have you tried  the solution mentioned above, it should certainly be the query you find.